# Finding empty cells in a specific row and writing smth in it

Tags: google-sheets

I need your help with my google spreadsheet.

I need a function which finds the 1.empty cell

in column a and writes "A23 is empty"
in column b and writes "B25 is empty" (23 and 25 are the numbers of rows)"
... ect.

in it.

I would appreciate your help and support!

Samy!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your spreadsheet for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question (please be more specific and include a picture of your spreadsheet), but what I think you're asking about is being able to read the content of a cell and in another cell output the message "XXX is empty"

Here is an example of an IF statement that returns the user-defined message "B30 is Empty":

```
=IF(B30="", "B30 is Empty")
```

- The way this is statement works is as follows: IF some condition / criteria (logical test) is TRUE, then return this value, otherwise return that value
- In the examples shown below, you'll notice I didn't specify anything in the return value part of the format, when this isn't specified, the equation will return "FALSE" if the IF condition specified isn't met.

In the picture below, the equation is looking at cell B30, since there is nothing, "B30 is Empty" will be written to cell A30.
[image]

In this picture, the equation is looking at cell B31, since there is text found, "FALSE" is written in cell A31.
[image]

In this picture, notice that I specified the return value to say "B31 is not Empty"

```
=IF(B31="", "B30 is Empty", "B30 is not Empty")
```

[image]

For more information, check out [IF Functions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xSEyv2o5tkyWPdOZcPZQH_Wf0qwYjQS2ecj_aqEFDss/edit)